# IntelliJ sbt project download sources behind proxy or from nexus server

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, sbt, intellij-scala

I am using `sbt` behind a proxy, with a corporate Nexus server.

My setup works correctly, using [CNTLM](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/)

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=10.0.2.2 -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128 -Dhttps.proxyHost=10.0.2.2 -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128"
SBT_OPTS="-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true"
```

and Nexus setup in `~/.sbt/repositories`

```
[repositories]
  local
  my-ivy-proxy-releases:http://company.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/ivy-releases/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  my-maven-proxy-releases:http://company.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/mvn-repositories/
```

All works correctly, even the "titled problem", if managed by sbt, fe:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% spark-core % "1.6.1" withSources())
```

can download the sources:
[image: downloading sources]

But if I want to use the build in IntelliJ "download sources" button:

[image: button]

it will give me a connection error:

[image: error]

What am I missing? I even looked at the IntelliJ logs, but they dont tell much

```
2017-04-07 10:52:24,002 [89494035]   WARN - r.InternetAttachSourceProvider - Connection problem. See log for more details. 
com.intellij.jarFinder.SourceSearchException: Connection problem. See log for more details.
    at com.intellij.jarFinder.MavenCentralSourceSearcher.findSourceJar(MavenCentralSourceSearcher.java:65)
    at com.intellij.jarFinder.InternetAttachSourceProvider$2$1.run(InternetAttachSourceProvider.java:134)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:726)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$6.run(CoreProgressManager.java:410)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.a(ApplicationImpl.java:594)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-04-07 10:52:38,562 [89508595]   WARN - der.MavenCentralSourceSearcher - Remote host closed connection during handshake 
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:992)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.openConnection(HttpRequests.java:511)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.access$300(HttpRequests.java:61)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestImpl.getConnection(HttpRequests.java:289)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestImpl.getInputStream(HttpRequests.java:298)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestImpl.getReader(HttpRequests.java:316)
    at com.intellij.jarFinder.SourceSearcher$1.process(SourceSearcher.java:76)
    at com.intellij.jarFinder.SourceSearcher$1.process(SourceSearcher.java:72)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.lambda$doProcess$0(HttpRequests.java:420)
    at com.intellij.util.net.ssl.CertificateManager.runWithUntrustedCertificateStrategy(CertificateManager.java:349)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.doProcess(HttpRequests.java:420)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.process(HttpRequests.java:395)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.access$100(HttpRequests.java:61)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestBuilderImpl.connect(HttpRequests.java:263)
    at com.intellij.jarFinder.SourceSearcher.readDocumentCancelable(SourceSearcher.java:72)
    at com.intellij.jarFinder.MavenCentralSourceSearcher.findSourceJar(MavenCentralSourceSearcher.java:39)
    at com.intellij.jarFinder.InternetAttachSourceProvider$2$1.run(InternetAttachSourceProvider.java:134)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:726)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$6.run(CoreProgressManager.java:410)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.a(ApplicationImpl.java:594)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    ... 39 more
2017-04-07 10:52:38,563 [89508596]   WARN - r.InternetAttachSourceProvider - Connection problem. See log for more details. 
com.intellij.jarFinder.SourceSearchException: Connection problem. See log for more details.
    at com.intellij.jarFinder.MavenCentralSourceSearcher.findSourceJar(MavenCentralSourceSearcher.java:65)
    at com.intellij.jarFinder.InternetAttachSourceProvider$2$1.run(InternetAttachSourceProvider.java:134)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:726)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$6.run(CoreProgressManager.java:410)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.a(ApplicationImpl.java:594)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am not sure but it seems I am not alone:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170595
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-165800

Comment: have you configured the proxy in the IDEA options?

Comment: yes I forgot to add this screen, but it is configured and connects successfully to any page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in Intellj and it is resolved.